# ¿Cuál es el evento de un activity después de utilizar el setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)?

Tags: android, eclipse, scroll

Estoy utilizando este método `(scroll)` para ir al ultimo de mi pantalla *(funciona correcto)*

```
fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
```

El detalle es que al utilizarlo justo después de cualquier

```
setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
```

No `scrollea` hacia abajo . debo suponer que trata de hacer el `scroll` cuando aún no se muestra en pantalla los datos del `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`

¿Alguna forma de solucionarlo? o en que evento se utiliza después de utilizar `setVisibility`

Answer (score 0):

Una opción que no me parece demasiado descabellada es hacer una `Custom View`, sobreescribir el método `setVisibility()`, hacer un `super()` y ya ahí llamar de alguna forma a la actividad para que refresque el comportamiento, bien usando una `Interface`o un bus de eventos.